# How to pass a 2D array to a Stored procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I'm trying to pass a 2D array from by `C#.NET` program to a stored procedure in `SQL Server 2005`. I dont know how to accomplish this. I'm gathering my data in a `DataGridView`.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support arrays as such.

Depending on how much data you have, you can do something like this: [How to Pass and Handle a Delimited String similar to handling an Array() of Values](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=StringArrayInput&referringTitle=Home).

You can also read Erland Sommarskog's article on the subject of [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) which outlines various different approaches to tackling the problem.

Comment: I guess I'll divide the data and go with this one. Thanks. :)

Comment: It appears that the first link is not valid any more.

Answer (score 2):

At *SqlServerCentral* there's an excellent [article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) by Jeff Moden on how to split a CSV list in Sql server. The *tally table* approach is also shown in the article by Erland Sommarskog, but this one seems to use slightly different concepts. So it might be worth comparing performance of the two.